# Update lbl.Text in asp.net when Status set to S

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to update lblMessage.Text when StatusICCID set to 'S'. Some times working and return value and sometimes it's not working and loop for ever. Please i would love to have your advice here for better code please. Thank you

```
 DataTable dt = ch.GetDataByNumber(txtNumber.Text);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ch.UpdateICCIDByNumber(ICCID: txtICCID.Text, StatusICCID: "P", userid: Convert.ToInt32(value: Session["UserId"].ToString()), number: txtNumber.Text);
                while (true)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout: 2000);
                    dt = ch.GetDataByNumber(number: txtNumber.Text);
                    if (dt.Rows != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (dt.Rows[0][columnName: "StatusICCID"].ToString() != string.Format("S")) continue;
                        lblMessage.Text = dt.Rows[0]["MessageICCID"].ToString();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you ensure that the value in the db is of S and not s. Try using string comparison. Ordinalignorecase.

Comment: It's always return S. I did checked it. Any advice plz? Thank you

Comment: Please guys advice me? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Oops, why are you using string.format for s, use it straight

Comment: I did change it to straight 'S'. still in somehow failed to catch the status 'S' and loop until timeout. Any advice please? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure on what conditions you are going to set the "StatusICCID" column as "P" based on the correct conditions. Because, you are setting "P" all the times. You should have logs or traces in place to figure out the value of the column when an infinite loop occurs. It is difficult to think your business logic and figure out the right problem. Please do log and post your findings here.